# Internet connectivity listener

Tags: java

Сейчас у меня есть ручная проверка интернет-соединения перед каждым методом, требующим интернет-соединение.
А как можно сделать постоянный "слушатель" интернет-соединения?
Так?

```
while (true) {
    checkInternet();
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

Хорошая ли это практика?

Comment: Не совсем, если такая проверка встречается повсеместно в коде, лучше поместите эту логику проверки в атрибут, которым декорируйте нужный метод. Затем сконфигурируете какой-нибудь IoC для вызова данного атрибута перед вызовом метода, отмеченного им и требующего проверки соединения.

Comment: Хм. А что вы собираетесь делать, если соединение вдруг пропало? Или если до начала метода оно было, а пропало во время выполнения?

Comment: @VladD, я как понимаю, он хочет просто проверить и все. Т.е. убедиться в наличии самого факта.

Comment: @sp7: Ну... А зачем проверять, если ничего после этого не делать? Тогда можно и не проверять в принципе.

Comment: @VladD Я думал, вам не будет интересно, для чего мне нужна эта проверка. У меня приложение, которое работает с VK API. И перед каждым методом, требующим интернетом вызывается проверка интернета. При отсутствии интернета немного меняется GUI приложения и изменяются некоторые данные.

Comment: @thejadefalcon: А, понятно. Тогда, конечно, нужно. Но в любом случае, даже если проверка показывает, что интернет есть, его может в любой момент не стать. Поэтому все методы должны быть к этому готовы, надеяться на предварительную проверку не стоит.

Симулировать такую ситуацию легко: вставьте `Sleep` в какой-нибудь метод и выключите модем во время `Sleep`'а.

Comment: @VladD Я верю. Тогда, получается, нужно хотя бы каждую секунду проверять интернет, а это затратно как-то.

Comment: @thejadefalcon: Ну, можно и не перепроверять. Просто если во время пробега какого-нибудь из методов, требующих интернет-соединения, связь пропадёт, то метод скорее всего вывалится с исключением. Вам нужно это исключение поймать и перепроверить _в этот момент_. Плюс стоит перепроверять _перед_ вызовом метода на всякий случай (чтобы поменять UI). Плюс в фоновом режиме время от времени.

Comment: @VladD Пытаюсь обработать отсутствие интернета так:

`    try {
    player = new MP3Player(new URL(onlinelink));
           player.play();      
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {       System.out.println("Ошибка воспроизведения");
}`

Но не удается: Unreachable catch block for UnknownHostException
Не могу понять, как мне обработать это исключение

Comment: @thejadefalcon: Очевидно, ваш код внутри `try`-блока не декларирует (и следовательно, не бросает) `UnknownHostException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант один**

Обычная моя практика - если интернет-соединения нету, значит запрос не отработает, значит меняем UI. Отсюда - проверка перед запросом лишняя.

**Вариант два**

```
public boolean isOnline() { 
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Вариант три**

Сделать бродкастЛистенер, который будет слушать смену состояния:

```
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
```

P.S. Забыл ответ на вопрос: практика фиговая, хотя кому судить. =)